# how to get top 5

Tags: mysql

I have table(data) having category(0=picture,1=video,2=music) views(numbers of views)
I want to write query that gets top5 pictures or top5 videos.

for example.

select * from data where category=0 sort by top 5 views.

Sorry I am not good at sql.
Any thought
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` to sort, and `LIMIT` to... limit.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE category = 0 ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5
```